# Do I have to force push from my local repo to my origin when rebasing from upstream during a pull-request?

Tags: git, github, rebase, pull-request

Given the following scenario:

1. I fork repo `A` [`HEAD` points to `c0`]
2. I commit locally [`l0`], push to origin and create PR
3. The upstream repo owner comments on my PR and asks me to rebase
4. I fetch from upstream/master (it's `HEAD` now points to `c1`) and rebase against it (so I have `c0`->`c1`->`l0`)
5. I commit locally [`l1`] the changes and try to push to origin

At this point my push is declined since my local and my origin have diverged and I find that I need to force push my local master to my origin in order for the PR to be correct (i.e. only contain `l0` and `l1`).

**My question is whether force-pushing is the common practice or am I making a mistake somewhere along the line**? The way I understand it once I push to my origin and rebase locally from upstream the history diverges and force is required.

**Update:**
I've come to learn that I am doing a mistake and that is that I'm rebasing during the PR. a "forker" should merge from upstream and that will not rewrite his history on origin and so not cause any issues.
I've accepted the answer below as it is possible the question wasn't phrased clearly enough to reflect that I'm questioning the entire process inclusive of merge vs. rebase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, force-pushing is **OK**. Git is preventing you from pushing normally as a safety mechanism to prevent you from accidentally overwriting your original branch. But in this case, you actually do want to overwrite it.

The only other case where a force-push would not necessarily be a good idea is if your branch was being shared with other people, who have copies of your old commits. Even in this case, a force-push is a feasible option, but it just means that everyone who has your old commits has to redo or rebase their work on top of your new commits, which can be difficult to coordinate, and a lot of extra work.

Comment: Thanks, Do you have by any chance any references to git mans or something of the sort? I was hoping for some "proof" which I can take back to my team members.

Comment: What kind of "proof" are you looking for? That doing a force-push is ok in this case? Or are you looking for git documentation in general?

Comment: The former. I read quite a few tutorials and blog-posts about github PR and the few that mentioned force-pushing did it offhandedly and without saying this is *the way* for the above scenario. I was hoping for a few links of that sort (hopefully of git authoritative figures :-)

Comment: @Ittai have you tried asking the upstream repo's owner about it? If he asked you to rebase, he should know as well that it's going to require you to force-push to your repo.

Comment: I am the upstream owner :-) This is for private GitHub repos for my company which we're trying to evaluate and I've encountered several problems with my "users" submitting bad PRs. I'm trying to investigate this issue to formulate a how-to guide. I think I'll give the answer another day to rest and then accept your answer if there won't be any more info.